# Anyone did php codeigniter pagination with sorting?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i'm working in php codeigniter. and i worked with pagination but how to sorting the field data like a Datatable pagination. Please help me

Comment: This link may help http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-from-scratch-displaying-sorting-tabular-data--net-14333 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXv2_s61qgM

Comment: use bootstrap datatables

Answer (score 1):

add following code in top of your view

```
$page = (int)$this->uri->segment(3);
if($page==0) { $page=1; }
$order_seg = $this->uri->segment(5,"asc"); 
$order= ($order_seg == "asc") ? "desc" :  "asc";
```

use following with your table header

```
<th><a href="<?php echo base_url().'test/view/'.$page.'/f_name/'.$order; ?>">First Name</a></th>
```

and apply parameter to  your controller function view() like,

```
function view($page=1,$sort='f_name',$order='desc'){}
```

and pass this to your model like

```
$data['result']=$this->test_Model->view((($page-1)*$config['per_page']),$config['per_page'],$sort,$order);
```

hope this will work after applying above..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ASC or DESC order clause in your query. your data will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

In view, between tag form:

```
<!--Código para capturar la ordenación-->
  <input type="hidden" id="orderby" name="orderby" value="<?php if (isset($orderby)) echo $orderby; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="tipoOrderby" name="tipoOrderby" value="<?php if (isset($tipoOrderby)) echo $tipoOrderby; ?>">
```

If you put this piece of code in your head table in view:

```
 <thead>
              <tr>
                <th> Column 1 <a  href="#" data-type="order" data-field="column1"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></a></th>
                <th> Column 2 <a href="#" data-type="order" data-field='column2'><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></a></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
```

In jquery (file.js), (could be improved by you):

```
// Código para controlar la ordenación de la tablas
      $(document).find('a[data-type="order"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).data("field") == document.form1.orderby.value) {
          if (document.form1.tipoOrderby.value == "ASC") {
            $(this).data("order", "DESC");
            $("i", this).addClass('fa-sort-desc');
          } else {
            $("i", this).addClass('fa-sort-asc');
            $(this).data("order", "ASC");
          }
        } else {
          $("i", this).addClass('fa-sort');
          $(this).data("order", "ASC");
        }
        $(this).click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          document.form1.orderby.value = $(this).data("field");
          document.form1.tipoOrderby.value = $(this).data("order");
          document.form1.submit();
        });
      });
```

In Codeigniter controller:

```
   if($form_data['orderby'] == ""){ //Default sort
      $orderby = "name";
      $tipoOrderby = 'ASC';
    }
    else{
      $orderby = $this->input->post('orderby');
      $tipoOrderby = $this->input->post('tipoOrderby');
    }
  //Returns values view
  $data['orderby'] = $orderby;
  $data['tipoOrderby'] = $tipoOrderby;
```

Last, you should include this in your query model =)

```
$query = $this->model->get($pages, $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']), $where, $orderby, $tipoOrderby);
```

Any doubts?